# To display only 2 digits after decimal point in FORTRAN 77 .

Tags: macos, precision, gfortran, fortran77

I want "3.66" as  the final result when I take avg of 3 nos. date type i used is DOUBLE PRECISION (double precision floating point number). The Answer that I receive when I do avg of these 3 nos (8+1+2) / 3.0 is 3.66666667 instead.

How can I display the value with exactly two digits of precision to the right of the decimal point ?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
write(output_unit,'(f4.2)') 3.66666667
```

then refer to your favourite Fortran tutorial or reference material and learn about *data edit descriptors*.